# Creating "Gridlines" for a table layout panel

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

Is there a way I can create a thick line as a row/column border for every third row?

I know that I can border every cell with `.CellBorderStyle` but that does not allow me to change anything for individual cells, or rows, or columns, as far as I can see.

How can I do this?

Comment: @HansPassant mind adding some detail to that?